# pick image and send email?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent

Good morning to everyone,i am an inexperienced developer and i need you..
i have this code to pick an image and send(to attachment)for email...
please help me because this code failed.

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
private static final int REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE = 0;
Uri selectedImage;

public void galleria(View v){
     Intent in = new        Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
         startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);  
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

        switch(requestCode) { 
        case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
        if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
           Uri selectedImage = imageReturnedIntent.getData();         
        final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
          emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
          emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"stefano.pietrella@gmail.com"});
          emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Object");
          emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message...");

                            //Uri attachment = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/fil.txt");
          emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,selectedImage);
          startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));            
            }
        }
    }
```

#### Logcat

```
02-21 09:53:20.359: E/AndroidRuntime(16440): FATAL EXCEPTION: 
main 02-21 09:53:20.359: E/AndroidRuntime(16440): java.lang.IllegalStateException: 
Could not find a method k(View) in the activity class com.supermoney.campionatoruzzle.LeagueSummaryV2 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'buttonStartMatch2' 
02-21 09:53:20.359: E/AndroidRuntime(16440): at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3678) 
02-21 09:53:20.359: E/AndroidRuntime(16440): at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)
```

Comment: what happened? please add logcat

Comment: when i click the second button to send email:
02-21 09:53:20.359: E/AndroidRuntime(16440): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-21 09:53:20.359: E/AndroidRuntime(16440): java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not find a method k(View) in the activity class com.supermoney.campionatoruzzle.LeagueSummaryV2 for onClick handler on view class android.widget.Button with id 'buttonStartMatch2'
02-21 09:53:20.359: E/AndroidRuntime(16440):  at android.view.View$1.onClick(View.java:3678)
02-21 09:53:20.359: E/AndroidRuntime(16440):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4211)

Comment: your layout is wrong. most likely you have a android:onclick="k", which doesn't make much sense.

Answer (score 0):

from your log cat put later in comment it seems that you have put an onclick method k in xml and dont have a declaration in java counter part

```
private static int RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE = 1;
    private static final int PICK_FROM_GALLERY = 2;
    private static final int REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE = 0;
    Uri selectedImage;

public void galleria(View v){
 Intent in = new        Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK,android.provider.MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI);
     startActivityForResult(in, RESULT_LOAD_IMAGE);  
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent imageReturnedIntent) { 
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, imageReturnedIntent); 

    switch(requestCode) { 
    case REQ_CODE_PICK_IMAGE:
    if(resultCode == RESULT_OK){  
       Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse("file://"+  getRealPathFromURI(imageReturnedIntent.getData());         
    final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
      emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"stefano.pietrella@gmail.com"});
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Object");
      emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Message...");

                        //Uri attachment = Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/fil.txt");
      emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,selectedImage);
      startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send email..."));            
        }
    }
}
```

as if you pick from galery instead of path it returns a content:// uri

```
         Uri selectedImage = Uri.parse("file://"+  getRealPathFromURI(imageReturnedIntent.getData())
```

try this -- if from galery and if from file manager go for your previous content can be done inside an if condition check weather the data contains mnt/ then its the real path go for your aproach else use this code

```
   public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
    String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
    Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    return cursor.getString(column_index);
}
```

Comment: sorry @droidhot but the method getRealPathFromURI is undefined...help me please..

Comment: public String getRealPathFromURI(Uri contentUri) {
       String[] proj = { MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA };
       Cursor cursor = managedQuery(contentUri, proj, null, null, null);
       int column_index = cursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA);
       cursor.moveToFirst();
       return cursor.getString(column_index);
   }
with this is ok!!!!!!!!!! thank you